# How to send dataset in Web Activity? ADF

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-data-factory

I want to publish data into a Service Bus, from my Storage Account.

I already tried send a simple body and it works fine. But i dont know how should set a data set.

[Web Activity Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znT0r.png)

When i run this activity into a pipeline, this send

```
{
    "myMessage": "Sample",
    "datasets": [{
        "name": "MyDataset",
        "properties": {
            ...
        }
    }],
    "linkedServices": [{
        "name": "MyStorageLinkedService1",
        "properties": {
            ...
        }
    }]
}
```

and i want send data from the file in dataset. Anyone know how i should set web activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using **"Copy Activity"**.

Here is a quick demo that I made :
I used JsonPlaceHolder API , I want to modify the array and add a custom value by doing a **PUT** request.
check it out here : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/
please read carefully **"Updating a resource"**

Here is a Json that I want to modify , I added it as a Dataset in ADF.
[image]

The main idea is to set the Dataset as a source and the sink is a REST API method so we are sending the Dataset as an input to the POST request in Copy activity.

**Copy activity:**

**Source:**
[image]

**Sink:**
[image]

You can read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#dataset-properties

Here is the output of the Copy Activity:
[image]