# How to pass key value parameters in ADF web activity when Content-Type is multipart/form-data

Tags: azure-data-factory, multipartform-data

I have a use case where we must pass username, password, grant_type, client_id, and client_secret via form-data in Azure Data Factory Web Activity.
Concatenating keys and values in the request body returns the below error. I am using the POST method and below is the header information.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72871073/how-to-send-dataset-in-web-activity-adf/72882006#72882006 
and let me know if it did not answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use post method in your web activity and provide your credentials under body.

```
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={your client id}&client_secret={ client secret}&scope=API
```